# C# Inline Expression Unanticipated Rendering

Tags: html, asp.net

Why is the following code displaying

> ">Text

```
<asp:Label ID="idlabel" runat="server" style='display:<% Eval(mystring.ToLower().Contains("search")) ? "none;" : "block;" %>' ClientIDMode="Static">Text</asp:label>
```

Comment: For starters, the closing tag should be `</asp:Label>`, not `</label>`. I'm assuming that's a typo though.

Comment: This yields "Newline in constant"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<asp:Label ID="idlabel" runat="server" style='<%# "display: " + Eval(mystring.ToLower().Contains("search") ? "none;" : "block;"  ) %>' ClientIDMode="Static">Text</asp:Label>
```